# Checking a false value in Meteor MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to make a filtered search module with meteor. I want my users to precise their serach by adding filters.

With this :

```
if(!options.natives.length)
        return Meteor.users.find({
            'profile.languages.learning': {$in: options.learning}
    });
    else if(!options.learning.length)
        return Meteor.users.find({
            'profile.languages.native': {$in: options.native}
        });
    else if(!options.learning.length && !options.native.length)
        return null;
    else
        return Meteor.users.find({
            $or: [
                {'profile.languages.native': {$in: options.natives}},
                {'profile.languages.learning': {$in: options.learning}}
            ]
        });
return Meteor.users.find({
      $and: [
        {$or {'profile.languages.native': {$in: options.natives}}, NoMatchingLang},
        {'profile.languages.learning': {$in: options.learning}}
      ]
```

My problem is that `profile.languages.learning` is an array, and I want that at least ONE of it's row matches `{$in: options.learning}`.

What do you think is the best way to do so ?

Thanks, 
David

Comment: Hi!

options.learning is a single object or an array?

Comment: It is an array, I forgot to precise. Options.native too. profile.learning is an array, and profile.native is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually already handled by $in per the [Mongo Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) - if the field contains an array, the selector will match documents that have at least one element matching across both arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I should pay more attention to the doc, i read ti but didn't got that.